# PHP Query with a multiple resoruces (results) to a one string?

Tags: php

Im trying to get a (multiple) results - resources actually from one Query, ready to be exploded(). I did it troughout while() command, but its quite complicated. All I need is resources.

Like "SELECT id FROM..." what are 1,2,3,4,5...

to output like this..

1,2,3,4,5

Can this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using **group_concat** in your query.

> SELECT group_concat(id) as id 
>   FROM....

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 1):

use `GROUP_CONCAT()` function

see this link http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/mysql-the-group_concat-function/